# Luna - Could not create the view: org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.ServersView

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

I am using Luna "**eclipse-java-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64**" I am not able to open the server view, it is giving error "**Could not create the view: org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.ServersView**".

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is at the install, if you choosed the java development environtment, the web development tools doesn't install. You must to go to the Install New software, and search for web development tools like the pic.

[Eclipse - Help - Install New Software...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTYFQ.png)

Good Look!

Answer (score 2):

That build of Eclipse Luna just contains code for Java developers. The view that cannot be found is part of the Web Developers component of Eclipse.

You can either install the missing components in your existing Eclipse or download a version of Eclipse which contains that view (maybe 'Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers'). Also consider moving to Eclipse Mars which is newer.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case ...

If you have upgraded your eclipse to Luna from an older version, you need to let Luna construct your new workspace, and then copy and import projects from your old workspace. Otherwise many problems, such this, would hamper the proper functioning of your workspace. For example, Maven may somehow not resolve properly. Your server view will be referencing for resources in a version of WST non-existent in the new IDE version.

When you upgrade from Luna to Mars, you will have to let Mars reconstruct your workspace again.